# URL Redirection in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, webforms

I was working on a Website which was earlier built with ASP.NET Web Forms and now is built with ASP.NET MVC.

We made the new MVC version live last week.

But the old login url which is ***www.website.com/login.aspx*** has been bookmarked by many users and they still use that and hence they get 404 errors.

So I was wondering which would be the easiest and best way to redirect the user from the old url to the new mvc url which is ***www.website.com/account/login***

Like this login url, I am expecting the users may have bookmarked few other urls also, so what will be the best way to handle this ?

Comment: why not keep the old page and redirect from it. web forms and mvc routes can go-exist in the same project...

Comment: Have removed the old project completely

Comment: you can check url in global.asax file...if url is www.website.com/login.aspx then you can redirect user to www.website.com/account/login

Comment: Is this a URL thing or just a rogue page that got favoritized? if the second, recreate a webforms page (login) as well as any other favored potentials and have them redirect to latest-and-greatest...

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [`URL Rewrite module`](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) in IIS. It's as simple as putting the following rule in your `<system.webServer>` section:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Login page redirect" stopProcessing="true">  
                <match url="login.aspx" />  
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="account/login" />  
            </rule>  
        </rules>
    </rewrite>

    ...
</system.webServer>
```

The module is very powerful and allows you any kind of rewrites and redirects. Here are some other [`sample rules`](http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/).

Answer (score 5):

in the global.asax

```
void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        //HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;
        //HttpContext context = app.Context;

        string reqURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;

        if(String.compare(reqURL, "www.website.com/login.aspx")==0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("www.website.com/account/login");
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can implement other logic to match the url as well

Comment: Awesome i use this to do 301 redirects that are needed.